# Unable to read memory MFC C++ with openCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, mfc

I have built a MFC C++ application on a windows 7 computer using Visual studio 2017 and it runs fine. But, when I move this project over to my home computer which is running windows 10 with the same version of Visual studio I get an error during runtime that seems to come from the openCV library. I have been debugging the error, and believe it is a conflict between MFC, and openCV.

The problem starts here. The object is initialized, but when it loads the model it breaks. I have debugged the facemark object and have found that the cv::Algorithm property has a value of "Unable to read memory", which I believe is where this starts.

```
Ptr<Facemark> facemark = FacemarkLBF::create();
facemark->loadModel("lbfmodel.yaml");
```

facemark->fit has three arguments. The first argument is an image, which is the current frame being passed, then faces which is just the rectangle for where the faces were detected, and landmarks. When this function returns true the parameter landmarks doesn't receive any data, but when I run this on my windows 7 machine it does. This is why I believe the problem starts when I am trying to load the lbfmodel because it is not able to load the model correctly.

```
    std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point2f> > landmarks;
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    faces.push_back(face.faceLocation());

    // Search for landmarks
    if ( facemark->fit(frame, faces, landmarks) )
    {
        // This function does not work anymore because landmarks is empty.
        face.map2DPointsTo3DPoints(landmarks);
```

I have quadruple checked that my librarys are all linked correctly, and even rebuilding openCV with cmake and linking all the dependencies again, but it has done nothing. I believe there is some type of conflcit between MFC C++ and openCV, but I have not been able to figure it out. I would appreciate any feedback or ideas on debugging this.

Comment: You have a bug in your code, somewhere. The bug can be anywhere. Just because a program starts going off the rails in one particular place doesn't mean that this is where the bug is. C++ doesn't work this way. Unfortunately, there is no cookie-cutter, paint-by-numbers recipe to fix this kind of bug every time it occurs. Only you have the complete source code, and you'll just have to figure out where the bug is, and fix it. As you gain experience, over time, you will learn and acquire your own particular debugging techniques for tracking down and fixing bugs.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the quick feedback. I'll try searching deeper to the to find the problem, but I'm troubled by how it works with windows 7 machines, but not windows 10.

Comment: That means absolutely nothing. A bug is not guaranteed to result in a crash 100% of the time. If a bug in your code results in some unallocated memory getting scribbled over, via a bad pointer, and it just so happens that on Windows 7 the memory block is completely unallocated, so the overwritten memory gets completely ignored; and then because Win 10's runtime library uses different memory allocation algorithms, now the same code ends up scribbling over some other unrelated vector, or other object, which now results in a crash. Doesn't mean this is exactly what your bug is, just an example.

Comment: It would certainly help if we could see the exact error message you are seeing.